# Is $7^{101}+8^{101}$ divisible by 25? If not, what is $ 7^{101} + 8^{101} \bmod 25$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I derived is: $$\begin{align}7^{101}+8^{101} &\equiv (5+2)^{101}+ (5+3)^{101} \\
&\equiv 2^{101}+101\cdot5\cdot2^{100}+3^{101}+101\cdot 5\cdot 3^{100} \\
&\equiv 2^{101}+(100+1)\cdot5\cdot 2^{100}+3^{101}+(100+1)\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2^{100}\\
& \equiv 2^{101}+5\cdot 2^{100}+3^{101}+5\cdot3^{100} \pmod {25}. 
\end{align}$$
Then I don't know what's the next step.

Comment: Note that $7^{20}\equiv 8^{20}\equiv 1\pmod {25}$.

Comment: Your second step is inaccurate, according to direct calculation using /usr/bin/bc: `7^101 + 8^101 - 2^101 - 3^101 - 5*101*2^100 - 3*101*2^100 = 16296310452011456063453504919809408989929161337969350475710120910994133492033819608817296875`

Comment: I think OP meant $\equiv$ not $=$, in which case your giant value is divisible by $25$... @RossPresser

Comment: Oh.. sorry, hadn't thought of that sort of typo.

Answer (score 6):

By *[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)*, for any $n$ coprime with $25$, $n^{\varphi(25)}=n^{20}\equiv1\mod25$, hence $n^k\equiv n^{k\bmod20}\mod25$, so that
$$7^{101}+8^{101}\equiv 7+8=15\mod 25.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the [lifting the exponent lemma](https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvNC81LzYyZTQ0NjJlOGZhYzkwMmQwNzAxOTgyOTViMjY1Y2I2NGRhNjcx&rn=TGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm):

$v_5(7+8)^{101}=v_5(7+8)+v_5(101)=1+0=1$, so $5^2\not\mid (7+8)^{101}$

<sup>The link is for the pdf-file called *Lifting The Exponent Lemma* by Amir Hossein Parvardi.</sup>

Comment: I think that lemma might be more than what the OP bargained for.